# how to pause and rewind swf flash using SWF Object

Tags: flash, swfobject

i used http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ SWF object to play the swf file. I am able to embed and play  but i am not getting any api java script to pause,rewind forward API for that any one done this ?

Answer (score 2):

SWFObject is just a tool for embedding Flash content in a webpage.  If you want to control the flow of your SWF with JavaScript you will have to communicate with it using [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

This will require you to to code the functionality you require in Flash, and then expose those functions using ExternalInterface so that you can call them from your page using JavaScript.